Who acts as a conformist in the Customer/Supplier relationship in DDD?
In the context of Domain-Driven Design (DDD), the Customer/Supplier pattern describes a relationship between two bounded contexts where one context (Customer) relies on the services provided by another context (Supplier).
I am trying to understand the concept of a "conformist" in relation to this pattern. Specifically, I would like to know:
Who acts as a conformist in the Customer/Supplier relationship?
What does it mean for a context to be conformist in this scenario?

In a Conformist relationship, the downstream team uses the same model as the upstream team.
In the Customer/Supplier pattern, the customer is usually the downstream team.
So the customer (and not the context) would be the conformist.
I often use this cheatsheet to explain the different Context Map patterns to the teams I work with.
